# SQL Update Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables, Products and ShoppingCart and I would like to update and decrease the product's 'Quantity' of the Products table based on the Product name and Quantity specified in the ShoppingCart. How can i do this?

Table: Products
Fields: ProductName, ProductQty

Table: Shopping Cart
Fields: ProductName, ProductQty

Access DB

Comment: You need to give us more information about your tables, why don't you post their definition?

Comment: Also, is this supposed to run one time?, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What type of database is it? You will need a transaction to do that right and the syntax varies.

Comment: Yup run one time only. Access DB

Comment: Is this just homework or an actual e-commerce application (or something else entirely)?  If it's just homework, that's fine, but if this is something you are going to take live I hope you make sure you really know what you're doing first.

Comment: This is part of my homework. Lamak's response was what i was actually looking for. Thanks.

Comment: There is no harm in tagging with homework. Sometimes you get more help that way and it saves people getting very, very worried :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a product id. However:

```
 UPDATE Products p
 INNER JOIN [Shopping Cart] s
 ON p.[Product Name] = s.[Product Name]
 SET p.ProductQty = p.ProductQty - s.ProductQty
```

You should get rid of spaces in field and table names, as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what i wanted.