# Subtracting value from integer with UPDATE statement

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have an integer which stores a value (intChange) and I would like to use the UPDATE statement to subtract the value specified in intChange from ChangeQty in the Denomation table in my Access DB. How can i do this?

Comment: The denominatiom table actually holds the amount of coins in the machine. My program is simulating a vending machine and I would like to subtract the qty of coins from ChangeQty based on the intChange value.

Comment: Is this still homework? And why can you not work on the answer to your previous question, which is very similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131075/sql-update-statement

Comment: Hi Remou, I have to managed to solve it myself. This post can now be deleted. :)

Answer (score 3):

Below are assumption for this...

Below is what I have table...

```
itemId     quantity
  1          34
  2          24
  3          32
```

I Believe you want to update quantity if Item is sold... Right? If **yes**, below is what I will use in MYSQL

`UPDATE myTable SET quantity=(quantity-soldItem) where itemId=1`

I believe query would remain same in MS Access DB.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: I can confirm that this works great for MS SQL as well.