# Insert Inner Join Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables, `ShoppingCart` which holds items in basket and `Sales` which records new transactions. I would like to insert a new record into `Sales` table with the values in Item and Price of `ShoppingCart` table. So `Item` will join with `sProdName` and `Price` will join with `sPrice`. As for sPmtType, I want to just add the text `Cash`. Does inner join also work for INSERT statement? If so, how can i write the statement to achieve the above results? Using Access DB

```
TableA: ShoppingCart {Fields: Item, Price}
TableB: Sales {Fields: sProdName, sPrice, sPmtType)
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO TableX( columnA, columnB, ...) SELECT colA, colB, ... FROM tableA JOIN tableB`

Comment: You should not build your homework answers question by question on SO, especially of you are not flagging homework : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131075/sql-update-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is not properly normalized. Without joining the tables you can also do `SELECT - INSERT` statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO Sales (sProdName, sPrice, sPmtType)
SELECT Item as sProdName, 
       Price as sPrice, 
       'CASH' as sPmtType
FROM   ShoppingCart
```

Comment: I get the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @user1166862  your question lacks information. Please post the code to which you are using that query.